# how to generate day of its associate date in data grid view.net,C#

Tags: c#, window

I want to show my data grid view like this

e.g. 
 Collapse | Copy Code

```
set NO   date                 day

1        1/1/2005             Monday
2        7/1/2005             Monday
3        14/1/2005            Monday
4        21/1/2005            Monday
5        28/1/2005            Monday
6        5/2/2005             Monday
7        12/2/2005            Monday
8        19/2/2005            Monday
9        26/2/2005            Monday
```

as user enter the fist date in date cell , the day column should fill with day name and setNO fill with 1 now as he press enter key the cursor move to the next cell of date column increase date with 7 day set dayName to associate day cell and 2 for setNO...an so on...

Please tell me what I need to do.

thanks in advance

Comment: Use Date format - dd/MM/yyyy dddd

Comment: How is the date entered , what is the control textbox or datepicker?

Answer (score 0):

this is just a little startup to get the DateTime, you need to work it out for yourself

```
     // make some textboxes to ask for start date (and maybe ammount of increments)
        DateTime Date = new DateTime(2011, 11, 05);
        int steps = 7;

        for (int i = 1; i < steps; i++)
        {
            // make here a method to add a new line to datagridview
            // make use of these lines to et to your results
            string day = Date.DayOfWeek.ToString();
            int setNo = i;
            Date = Date.AddDays(7);                
        }
```